# Protractor: Test failing when values are equal to each other

Tags: angularjs, testing, protractor

Below is my protractor test that opens a dialog in an angular application. It adds correctly but the test fails even when the values are equal to each other.

I want to say it might have something to do with the whole ignoringSynchronization but then I run into the whole timeout waiting for the synchronization with the modal dialog that pops up or something.

The message is: Expected 'Potato' to equal 'Potato'. These are all just dummy values but yeah just to get the gist of it.

```
describe('someTest', function(){
// beforeEach(function(){
//     browser.get("url");

// })

it('Add Test', function(){
    browser.get("url");
    var testEle = element(by.model('ng-model'));
    testEle.$('[value="0"]').click();

    browser.waitForAngular();
    //grabbing first object from the ng-repeat
    testEle = element(by.repeater("ng-repeat").row(0));
    testEle.element(by.tagName('span')).click();

    //A modal dialog pops open with an input box so you can type stuff into it and will show options to auto complete
    //that you can click on

    //need this or else it will timeout waiting for angular to sync
    browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;


    var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
    browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(element(by.id('an_input_tag'))));
    testEle = element(by.id('an_input_tag'));
    testEle.sendKeys("Potat");
    browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(element(by.id('input_auto_completes'))));
    testEle = element(by.id('input_auto_completes'));
    testEle.click();
    browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(element(by.buttonText('Add'))));
    element(by.buttonText('Add')).click();

    browser.wait(EC.textToBePresentInElement(element(by.repeater("ng-repeat").row(0)), 'Potato'));
    testEle = element(by.repeater("ng-repeat").row(0)).element(by.className('className'));
    expect(testEle.getText()).toEqual('Potato');

 })
}
```

Comment: I see you have entered `Potat` in `sendKeys()` operation. Are you sure that data you passed is correct? Also can you check the text of the element is not modified in any way dynamically (make sure case of the letters match too)? Thanks

Comment: What if you would use `toContain` or `toMatch` - does it fail? Thanks.

Comment: @GirishSortur Oh yeah, sorry I didn't explain but when I do sendKeys("Potat"), there is a menu that drops down to auto complete so it auto completes it to 'Potato'. Which is why I wait and then click it. I tried testing for === and it does indeed fail but when I console.log .getText() it outputs 'Potato'. I'll try and fiddle around with it some more.

Comment: @alecxe I just tried toContain and toMatch and it still fails. I'll try and fiddle with it some more.

Comment: Try: 

expect(testEle.getAttribute("text")).toEqual('Potato');